# Molasses cookies - Do I need to start over?

Tags: sugar, cookies

I am making molasses cookies. I accidentally put a cup of sugar in the dry ingredients, when I was only supposed to have a cup of sugar creamed with shortening. Should I throw out my dry ingredients and start over or can I keep it and maybe my cookies will just be extra sweet?

Here is the recipe:

Ingredients:
1 cup shortening
1 egg
3/4 tsp vinegar
3 cups sifted flour
1 tsp salt
1 cup sugar
1/2 cup molasses
3/4 cup evaporated milk
3 tsp soda powder
1 tsp cinnamon

Cream shortening and sugar. Add egg and molasses, beat well. Stir in vinegar and milk. Mix and sift dry ingredients. Add to mixture. Drop from teaspoon on greased baking sheet. Bake at 350F for about 15 minutes.

Comment: Welcome Kayley, if you share the recipe, it will give us a better chance for a good answer. Just click the grey "edit" below your post to add information.

Comment: I have now added the recipe

Comment: why not test bake a few and check if the result is acceptable, or unsalvageable, or needs adjustments (like doubling the recipe around the existing mix)...

Comment: You don't want too much sugar. The point of creaming the shortening and sugar is to get the shortening "emulsified" a bit. You can't really mix milk and shortening. Think of vinegar and oil as opposed to just water and oil. If you have an electric mixer for all of this you should be able to overcome the problem. Just follow the rest of the sequence. You'll be able to use the mixer to brute force what you could have finessed by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to start over. The texture will be a little different than the original recipe but mixing the dry ingredients is not a huge mistake. Go ahead and bake the cookies according to the remaining recipe.

Comment: Sugar is not a "dry" ingredient. And adding it twice will definitely affect the outcome.